# Why does Jacob indicate "Expeditionary Forces" by performing a "digging" gesture with his hands?

Tags: fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

> Jacob: Yeah. I was part of the **expeditionary forces** there.

[image]

Why does Jacob indicate "Expeditionary Forces" by performing a "digging" gesture with his hands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Jacob's bio](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Jacob_Kowalski) he fought in the First World War.  As an American it is near 100% certain that he was a part of the [American Expeditionary Forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Forces) in France.  Given the nature of the fighting in that war, this would have involved a lot of digging trenches and earthworks.  Hence the "digging" gesture.

> The AEF helped the French Army on the Western Front during the Aisne
> Offensive (at the Battle of Château-Thierry and Battle of Belleau
> Wood) in the summer of 1918, and fought its major actions in the
> Battle of Saint-Mihiel and the Meuse-Argonne Offensive in the latter
> part of 1918.

Comment: And also demonstrating that he's not afraid of hard work, metaphorically speaking

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad joke.

> SCENE 9
>
> INT. BINGLEY'S OFFICE-MOMENTS LATER-DAY
>
> *Jacob is facing the imposing and impeccably suited Mr. Bingley. Bingley is examining Jacob's business proposal for a bakery.*
>
> *An uncomfortable silence. The sound of a ticking clock and Bingley murmuring.*
>
> *Jacob looks down at his pocket--the egg has started to vibrate.*
>
> BINGLEY
>
> You are currently working... in a canning factory?
>
> JACOB
>
> That's the best I can do-I only got back in '24.
>
> BINGLEY
>
> Got back?
>
> JACOB
>
> From Europe, sir. Yeah-I was part of the Expeditionary Forces there-
>
> ***Jacob is clearly nervous, miming a digging action to the words "Expeditionary Forces," in the vain hope that a joke might help his cause.***
>
> <sub>*(Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay)*</sub>

Comment: What is the joke?